# XML Layout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying a profile pic with name and email address in the linear Layout strangely this isn't coming up properly when I see in Graphical layout in eclipse I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is what I would like to expect:

[image]

Here is how it shows up:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_weight=".80"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="testing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="abc@abc.com"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong? Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: is this an xml for listView item??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your very first LinearLayout `(android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout")` should have `layout_height="wrap_content"`.  That's all :)

Comment: My bad.. I didn't try that part.. Thanks this worked!

Answer (score 1):

This will work according to your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_weight=".80"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="testing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="abc@abc.com"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

code will be like this;

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".20" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profilepic" >
    </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforText"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="left|center"
   android:layout_weight=".80"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="testing"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="abc@abc.com"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```